# Analytic iff Holomorphic on open domains of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I am reading through the proof of Griffiths and Harris on pages $2/3$. I am struggling with the proof of

$f$ is holomorphic iff $f$ is analytic.

They have a proof of holomorphicity and analaticity of function defined over open subsets of the complex plane. First I suppose that

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}=0.$$

I'd like to know where he uses this in proving there exists a converging power series, so first assuming $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}=0,$ does he use Cauchy Integral Formula? and this fact?

I also want to know what the most formal definition of $\textit{holomorphic}$ is vs. $\textit{analytic}$. From my understanding $f$ is holomorphic on some open $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ if for each $z \in U$, one has

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}=0.$$

And $f$ is analytic on all of $U$ is for each $z_0 \in U$ one can write $f$ as a power series centered at some $z_0 \in U$,

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n$$

such that the series converges on $U$.

First off, are these the more standard definitions of holo and analytic? Secondly, in proving holomorphic $\Rightarrow$ analytic, where do they use that the partial of the conjugate is zero? If anyone has a copy of Griffiths $\&$ Harris. Sorry if my question is too elementary, I am applying for PhDs for Fall 2022 and just wanna head start on some of the concepts I may encounter once there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition that an infinitely differentiable function $f$ is holomorphic on an open subset $U\subset\mathbb{C}$ if $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}= 0 $$

a perfectly good definition and is essentially just a restatement of the Cauchy Riemann equations. It seems in Griffiths and Harris they prove a generalized version of the Cauchy integral formula which holds for any $C^{\infty}$ function (which reduces to the standard version when $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}=0$) and use this to prove that such functions are analytic.

If you want to learn about the equivalent definitions of holomorphic/complex analytic functions and theorems about their equivalence I'd suggest a book specifically on complex analysis.

Comment: dude thanks a million! you 100% answered my question!! What text ? Alfohrs? Rudin? Conway? Gamelin Greene? @podiki

Comment: @HosseinSahebjame Most texts will cover this and what's best depends on your background. Something very approachable would be Complex analysis by Stein and Shakarchi. Ch1 Sec 2 and Ch2 Sec4 are probably the most relevant in that book.

Comment: Ah perfect, thanks! which Volume the Complex one? @podiki

Comment: I would reiterate that a solid background in complex analysis and some algebraic topology and differential geometry would precede wrestling with Griffiths and Harris.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a copy of that text book at hande, but the standard definition of holomorphic function is that it is a differentiable function, that is, that, for each $z_0$ in its domain, the limit

$$\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$$

exists.Quite often, but not always, it is added to the definition the condition that the domain of $f$ is an open subset of $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Carlos Santos I was wondering then why they require the partial with respect to the conjugate be zero as a part of the pure definition of holomorphic. Your definition sort of relies on us being defined over $\mathbb{R}$ I think because in the reals conjugating does nothing.

Comment: @Since I don't have a copy of that textbook at hand, I cannot comment it. But in the definition that I mentioned has the advantage of not requiring that we define $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\overline z}$ first.

Comment: True, this makes sense we have not written $f$ as a sum of its real and imaginary portions. I was just wondering in the complex case how $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}=0$ implies the existence of a (converging) power series.

Comment: Yes, it does, because it is actually equivalent to the fact that $f$ is holomorphic in the sense that I have mentioned in my answer (assuming that $\operatorname{Re}f$ and $\operatorname{Im}f$ are $C^1$ functions).